# Prove that $\frac{\sin t\pi}\pi\ge t-2t^3+t^4$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $t$ a real number such that $t\in[0,1]$, prove that:
$$\frac{\sin t\pi}\pi\ge t-2t^3+t^4$$
I considered the function obtained by subtracting the RHS from the LHS. When I differentiate it, it gIves something not obvious to study.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: No, thanks, it's *your* homework/exercise.

Comment: This was actually a little more interesting because of the asymmetry of the polynomial about $t=\frac12$, so it's a shame that it was closed.

Comment: In appearance, it is precisely the other way around but there are certain small interval which in effect  your inequality is true.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I consider the function $f(t)=\frac{\sin(t\pi)}{\pi}- t+2t^3-t^4$, When I differentiate it, it gaves something not obvious to stuty.

Comment: The question is clear and not trivial. Therefore it's understandable to ask here for a solution. Would be better to reopen it.

Comment: @Techer01 : $0\leq x\leq 1$ , $f(x):=\frac{1}{x^2}(1-\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x})$ : We have to show $f(x)\leq 2-x$ . This can be done by using $f(0)<2-0$, $f(1)=2-1$ and showing that $(2-x)'=-1\leq f’(x)\leq 0$ for all $x$ in the valid value range.

Comment: we need only one vote more to reopen!

Answer (score 2):

We need to show that

$$f(t)=\frac{\sin(t\pi)}{\pi}- t+2t^3-t^4\ge 0 \quad t\in[0,1]$$

let $t=x+\frac12$ with $x\in[-\frac12,\frac12]$ thus we need to show that

$$f(x)=\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\pi}-x^4+\frac32x^2-\frac5{16}\ge 0$$

since $f(x)$ is even we can consider $x\in[0,\frac12]$.

Note also that

- $f(0)=\frac1{\pi}-\frac5{16}>0$
- $f(1/2)=0$

then it suffices to show that $f(x)$ is monotonic on the inteval $x\in[0,\frac12]$.

Then consider

$$g(x)=f'(x)=-\sin \pi x+3x-4x^3$$

with

- $g(0)=0$
- $g(1/4)<0$
- $g(1/2)=0$

then it suffices to show that $g(x)\le 0$ on the interval $x\in[0,\frac12]$ which is true if we show that $g(x)$ has exactly one minimum on that interval.

Then consider

$$h(x)=g'(x)=-\pi\cos \pi x+3-12x^2$$

with

- $h(0)=3-\pi<0$
- $h(1/2)=0$

then it suffices to show that $h(x)=0$ has exactly one solution on the interval $x\in(0,\frac12)$ and hence exactly one maximum on that interval.

Then consider

$$l(x)=h'(x)=\pi^2\sin \pi x-24x$$

with

- $l(0)=0$
- $l(1/2)=\pi^2-12<0$

then it suffices to show that $l(x)=0$ has exactly one solution on the interval $x\in(0,\frac12)$ and hence exactly one maximum on that interval.

Then consider

$$m(x)=l'(x)=\pi^3\cos \pi x-24$$

with

- $m(0)=\pi^3-24>0$
- $m(1/2)=-24<0$

then it suffices to show that $m(x)=0$ has exactly one solution on the interval $x\in(0,\frac12)$.

Then consider

$$n(x)=m'(x)=-\pi^4\sin \pi x$$

which is negative on the interval $x\in(0,\frac12)$ and therefore on the interval $x\in(0,\frac12)$

- $m(x)$ has exactly one root
- $l(x)$ has exactly one maximum and one root
- $h(x)$ has exactly one maximum and one root
- $g(x)$ has exactly one minimum and is negative
- $f(x)$ is monotonic and positive

thus

$$f(x)=\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\pi}-x^4+\frac32x^2-\frac5{16}\ge 0\quad \square$$

Comment: Gimusi.Nothing much to contribute.Tried to show that f(t) is concave , the 2 zeroes are ok, and then concave would do, but f''(t) = -πsin(tπ) +12t -12t^2, this is not conclusive.  f''(0)=f''(1)=0. At t=1/2 f(t) = 3 -π<0 , does it stay negative?Assum,does not help much.:))

Comment: @PeterSzilas Peter could you please vote to reopen if you think that it is the case, Thanks!

Comment: Gimusi.Why would you want to reopen the case? You solved the problem, ok.I would not know what to add, but if you feel that it should be reopened I am with you.How do you vote to reopen, by the way:)

Comment: Near the “edit” button there is the “reopen” button, can you see it?

Comment: Got it.done.:))

Comment: @PeterSzilas Great! Thanks